# Javascript, Protractor and increment counters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, increment

I've already posted a similar question before but wanted to make it bit more clear and focused. So I'am writing here again (or should I keep editing the one I posted before?)

I am writing e2e test specs for angularJS using protractor.

Within the protractor spec, I'm also using JavaScript.

The problem is that JavaScript counter variables are not working as I intended.

I will show you code here:

```
// codes here within this describe block made me come back :( call this sample 1

//'use strict';

describe('list page ', function () {
    it('should list page', function () {

        browser.get('/list');

        var counterA = 0;

        element.all(by.repeater('page in pages')).each(function (page) {

            counterA++;
            //console.log(counterA);
        })

        //console.log(counterA);

        // Please be true assertion :(

        expect(counterA).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    })
});

// testing against protractor spec: wrote within the same js file. call this sample 2

bigitems = [["somevalue", "t", "y"], ["somevalue", "somevalue", "y"]];
counterB = 0;

for (smallitems in bigitems) {
    for (item in bigitems[smallitems]) {
        if (bigitems[smallitems][item] == "somevalue") { counterB++; }
    }
}

console.log(counterB)
```

#### One thing I noticed is that 'sample 2' counterB is working and returns '3' to console. 'sample 1', however, return 0 for counterA outside .each{} block.

here's console output.

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
3
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
.

Finished in 11.877 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures
```

#### and thank you again everyone helped me on this topic before.

Comment: `element` returns a `promise` which is `async` then console.log outside element will not be called after `.each` but somewhere in the middle

Comment: hm, shouldn't asyncness still trigger ++ operator?? counterA outside each{} still zero according to  expect(counterA).toBeGreaterThan(0); err message: Expected 0 to be greater than 0.

Comment: It would, but apparently the console.log outside element is called before first counterA++, you can `setTimeout(function(){console.log(counterA)}, 200)` and that will probably log other value as the element would trigger `++` by this time

Comment: still not getting it. Could anyone show me way to make that assertion true?

Comment: `expect(element.all(by.repeater('page in pages')).count()).toBeGreaterThan(0)` wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it that way because of the asynchronous nature of Javascript. That happens because *expect* does not wait for *element.all.each* to finish.

So you need to use promises to make it work. But the problem here is that element.all.each does not return a promise (at least not yet, see [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1330) for the current discussion).

There are a few alternatives for this to work.

-If all you want is to count the number of elements you can simply use this.

```
it('sample', function() {
  element.all(by.repeater('page in pages'))
    .then(function(elements){
      return elements.length;
    })
    .then(function(count){
      //console.log("...." + count);
      expect(count).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

-Or alternatively just this.

```
it('sample', function() {
  expect(element.all(by.repeater('page in pages')).count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

-If you really want to do the count manually you also have this option, although you will have to call *element.all* twice.

```
it('sample', function() {
  var count = 0;
  element.all(by.repeater('page in pages'))
  .then(function(){
    element.all(by.repeater('page in pages')).each(function(item){
      count++;
      //console.log(count);
    });
  })
  .then(function(){
    //console.log(count);
    expect(count).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

-Or this.

```
it('sample', function() {
  var counterA = 0;
  element.all(by.repeater('page in pages'))
    .then(function(elements){
      elements.forEach(function(entry){
        counterA++;
      });
    })
    .then(function(){
        //console.log(counterA);
        expect(counterA).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
});
```

-Or similarly this.

```
it('sample', function() {
  element.all(by.repeater('page in pages'))
    .then(function(elements){
      var counterA = 0;
      elements.forEach(function(entry){
        counterA++;
      });
      return counterA;
    })
    .then(function(counterA){
        //console.log(counterA);
        expect(counterA).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It did helped me a lot. I didn't use the first two options since I have inner loop where it needs to check 'if' condition before increment. I used the elements.forEach option. It worked out great! finally. Thank you. but now my loops looks way verbose and I'm starting to think that maybe protractor doesn't set to manually resolve 'promises' since mine looks like < click.then -> find.button.then -> click.then -> find.elements.then -> get text.then -> if match counter++ -> ... then expect counter to be greaterthan > Thank you very much for giving me valuable information and thank you to maurycy.